Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22! after checking output of sudo dmesg command logs
I am running AWS EC2 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS instance and also I did the configuration of wordpress according to this documentation. I issue I am getting is instance reachability check failed then It will be resolved by restarting instance. I want to dig depper is it aws issue or ubuntu misconfiguration. I am new to ubuntu your guidance will help me lot in learning process.
Thank you.
